# Bootstrap button don't have format or text

Tags: bootstrap-4

Well, probably this is a stupidity. I've been using bootstrap buttons without problem until now.

I have these lines:

```
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg" id="Asignaturas" [routerLink]="['/asignaturas']"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg" id="Universidades" [routerLink]="['/universidades']"></button>
</div>
```

but it appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fCms.png). Doesn't have format or text, and to be lg they are SO small... I don't know why :/

Comment: Well, they don't have any text, because you haven't given them any.  There's no content _inside_ the `<button>` tag.

Comment: omg, thank you... I've been working for so long I think lol